# Javascript popup print page blocking the parent actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent page calling the child popup page to show the print page. After redirecting to print page If I close the the child page I can do other activities in parent page, but when I minimize my Child page (print page) and try some activity it is not responding, after closing the Child page what ever I did it is recreating.

Code:

```
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('innerchartdiv');
var outerContainerDiv = document.getElementById('outerContainer');
var divToPrint = chartDiv.innerHTML;
setTimeout(function(){
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800px,height=800px');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><body align="center" style="margin:0% 17%;font-size:9px;">' +     chart+'</html>');
popupWin.document.close();
popupWin.focus();
popupWin.print();
popupWin.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you call print on the popup, it is the same as an alert box, it blocks the thread! I've had that problem before, and the answer is that the print dialogue will always block the JS thread.

This is the reason, many websites open a generated PDF in a new tab, rather than using the print dialogue. I know it's not the answer you want, but that's why people use custom alert boxes too. Blocking the execution of JS for the user interface ruins the user experience, and stops all animation and events firing, until you have clicked.

#### Alternative Suggestion:

You can't control the popup from JS, it literally has to be a hyperlink. However there is a way of doing this without the server. client side PDF generation tools and 'Blob URLs' work in modern browsers, so you can do client side PDF generation too. Try [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), I haven't used that one but it might do the trick.

ALSO:

Cross browser print css and sizing is not very uniform, so if you want to control the layout, again the PDF generation is by far the easiest option to ensure the page is printed in the intended way. I don't really love the PDF format, but that is the reason it's so popular.

Comment: And yes, even though technically it is a new pop-up window, it is still on the same JS thread. The full new window / new tab option is the only good solution I have found.

Comment: Even I have create with new Tab also it is not working.

Comment: You can't control it from JS, it literally has to just be a hyperlink. Obviously that means that printing sucks for anyone that doesn't have access to server side generation... However there is another option. There are some client side PDF generation tools and 'Blob URLs', so you can do client side PDF generation too. Try [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), I haven't used that one but it might do the trick.

Comment: I'll add that to my answer

Comment: There are some other libraries to generate PDF on the client side, but some of these require using Node.js, and browserify. Because of this I haven't suggested it in the answer, but there are a number of options. I wish the print dialogue didn't freeze the JS execution, but such is life!

Comment: I see this issue is in Chrome browser only. IE is working fine. :(

Comment: I cannot suggest the PDF solution enough. There are popup blocking issues and all sorts that you encounter trying to control this from the JS thread. I really have been there, and had a big fight with all the different browsers displaying, blocking. Chrome even crashed when I closed the pop-up window with the print dialogue still open... This is a world of pain. Don't do it :-/ It's not good enough, or consistently implemented enough to bother.